# Filtering sum data from 2 column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

I have some problem with my filter search......I want to get data from sum total_amount and unique_number...but it doesnt work.....i will show my function filter code in Controller....

```html
public function ifilter(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        $flag = 1;

        $title = 'Invoice Paid';

        $master = Master_lookup::where('type' , 'LIKE' , 'order_status')->select('name','id')->where('id', '=' , 9)->orWhere('id' , '=' , 10)->orWhere('id' , '=' , 11)->orWhere('id' , '=' , 12)->orWhere('id' , '=' , 13)->orWhere('id' , '=' , 14)->get();

        if (! empty($data)) 
        {
            $orders = Order::whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($data)
            {
                if(! empty($data['buyer']))
                {
                    $query->where('name' , 'LIKE' , '%'.$data['buyer'].'%');
                }
            })->whereHas('store' , function($query) use ($data)
            {
                if(! empty($data['store']))
                {
                    $query->where('name' , 'LIKE' , '%'.$data['store'].'%');
                }
            })->where(function($query) use($data)
            {
                if (! empty($data['number'])) 
                {
                    $query->where('number','LIKE','%'.$data['number'].'%');
                }
            })->where(function($query) use($data)
            {
                if (! empty($data['total-amount'])) 
                {
                    $query->where('total_amount', '=' , $data['total-amount'])->where('total_amount','=','total_amount+unique');
                }
            })->where(function($query) use($data)
            {
                if (! empty($data['total-transferred'])) 
                {
                    $query->where('proof_of_payment', '=' , $data['total-transferred']);

                }    
            })->where(function($query) use($data)
            {
                if (! empty($data['received-at'])) 
                {
                    $query->whereDate('received_at' , '=' , $data['received-at']);
                }
            })->where(function($query) use($data)
            {
                if (! empty($data['request-at'])) 
                {
                    $query->whereDate('request_payout_at', '=' , $data['request-at']);
                }
            })->whereHas('master' , function($query) use($data)
            {
                if (! empty($data['status'])) 
                {
                    $query->where('id' , '=' , $data['status']);
                }
            })->where('status', '=' , 10)
            ->with('user')
            ->paginate(10);    
            
            return view('orders.invoice-paid', compact('master' , 'orders' , 'title' , 'flag'));            
        }



    }
```

You can see my $data['total-amount']...i want to try sum 2 column...but it doesnt work.....i search my data and nothing to show...can you help me please....if you can,please show me the correct code...

Comment: If it was me, I'd forget about all the laravel stuff for now, and instead focus on the sql.